# Generalising a condition for differentiability from dimension $1$ to higher dimension

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, proof-verification

I am studying multivariate calculus from Tom M Apostol's book. I read the following theorem about differentiability of a function $F:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

> THEOREM 1:
>
> Assume that the parital derivatives $\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x_j}}$ exist for all $j$ and are continuous at $a\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Then $f$ is differentiable at $a$.

I am trying to generalise this sufficient condition for differentiability to higher dimensions. I am making the following claim:

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ be such that $f(a)=(f_1(a),\dots,f_m(a))$ where $f_k:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Assume that $\frac{\partial{f_k}}{\partial{x_j}}$ exists for all $j,k$ and is continuous at $a\in \mathbb{R}^n$. Then $f$ is differentiable at $a$.

Proof:

(1). By Theorem 1, we conclude that $f_k:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable. This means that there exists a linear map $T_{a}^{k}:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$f_k(a+v)=f_k(a)+T_{a}^{k}(v)+\|v\|E_k(a,v)$$
where $E_k(a,v)\rightarrow0$ as $\|v\|\rightarrow0$.

(2). Define $T_a:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ as $$T(y)=(T_a^1(y),\dots, T_a^m(y))$$
Then $T$ is linear as each $T_a^k$ is linear.

(3). Define $E$ as
$$E(a,v)=(E_1(a,v),\dots, E_m(a,v))$$
Then $E(a,v)\rightarrow0$ as $\|v\|\rightarrow 0$ (because $E_k(a,v)\rightarrow0$ as $\|v\|\rightarrow0$ for all $k$)

(4). We have $$f(a+v)=f(a)+T_{a}(v)+\|v\|E(a,v)$$ where $T_a$ is linear and $E(a,v)\rightarrow0$ as $\|v\|\rightarrow0$. This means that $f$ is differentiable.

Is my claim and the proof correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.